# git add all tracked files - also those in parent directory

Tags: git, git-add

Lets say I have a git root folder `mine_git`, which has a subdirectory `subdir` there. So I've worked a bit, and I'm in `subdir` - `git status` lists all changed files:

```
subdir$ git status -uno
# On branch master
# ...
#
#   modified:   mysubdirfile.txt
#   modified:   ../a-main-file.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

K, so I want to add all of these tracked and modified files to staging area (or cache? index? not sure of the name), so I can commit afterwards; so I issue:

```
subdir$ git add -u
```

... and then I check again:

```
subdir$ git status -uno
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   ...
#
#   modified:   mysubdirfile.txt
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   ...
#
#   modified:   ../a-main-file.txt
#
# Untracked files not listed (use -u option to show untracked files)
```

So, only those files under my current location are `git add`ed, and **not** those in parent/sibling folders - even if those files are tracked by this git repository, and show up in `git status`!

And then I usually have to manually copy paste filenames, so as to do `git add ../a-main-file.txt`. Obviously this is a pain - so is there some command which will add **all** files listed by `git status -uno`, regardless of if they are located below the current level or not?

Comment: `git add -u` works fine here

Comment: Thanks @maggick - as the answer below notes, it didn't work for me because I had an old version of git; cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of git (`2.4.3`) should do this already.  From `man 1 git-add`:

```
   -u, --update
       Update the index just where it already has an entry matching <pathspec>. 
       This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, 
       but adds no new files.

       If no <pathspec> is given when -u option is used, all tracked files in the entire
       working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the 
       current directory and its subdirectories).
```

That said, you could try something like `git add -u -- ../relative/path/to/project/root`.  I don't have an older git version handy, so I could not test it.

Comment: Thanks @suvayu - I use 1.7.9.5,  guess there is isn't such a functionality there ... thanks for the suggestion too, but that also requires manual copypaste of filenames... would be nice if someone could sometime come up with a script handling the old behaviour, though.. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Why do you say it requires copy paste of file names? Only the path to the top level directory should be enough I think, all the paths should not be required.